# KunderaException : execute_cql3_query failed: out of sequence response

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I am trying to insert rows in cassandra using kundera, but if a row with same Primary key already exists, I do a **delete + insert**.

It works fine with single thread and single node cluster. But when extended to 2 nodes and in multi threaded operation, I get the below error

**Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: execute_cql3_query failed: out of sequence response**

I am not using any batching here. batchSize=0 (not sure if that info would help)

Comment: Can you share the details of your cassandra properties xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by doing a Flush after delete.

Here was the sequence I followed which resolved the problem

1. Delete
2. **entityManager.flush()**
3. Insert